# Spring Many to many bidirectional saving data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I have two classes, whose tables have bidirectional relationship with each other. 
An Employee can be associated with multiple service categories and vice versa. The join table is declared within Service Categories class.

When I wish to save Employee object then nothing is saved within the join table, but if I try to print the employee related service categories, then I am getting all the details

```
if(employee.getServiceCategories()!= null && employee.getServiceCategories().size()>0){
  for(ServiceCategory serviceCategory : employee.getServiceCategories()){
    logger.debug("employee's serviceCategory id : " + serviceCategory.getId());
    logger.debug("employee's ServiceCat Name  : " + serviceCategory.getServiceCatName());
  }
}
```

> **Employee.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee extends BaseEntity {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy="employees")
  private List<ServiceCategory> serviceCategories = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

> **ServiceCategory.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "servicecategory")
public class ServiceCategory  extends BaseEntity {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Employee.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
  @JoinTable(name = "servicecategory_employee", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "servicecatid") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "empid") })
  private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Thanks for your help.

---

> **UPDATE**

I changed my code in Employee.java to

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="employees", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<ServiceCategory> serviceCategories = new ArrayList<>();
```

Also I am now using following code while saving the Employee in my DAO class `

```
public void addEmployee(Employee employee) throws SmrException {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.merge(employee);
        logger.info("Employee saved successfully, employee Details="
                + employee);
    }
```

But still the result remain same. I am unable to save data in the join table

Comment: You need to have `@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` on the `serviceCategories` field in the `Employee` class.

Comment: @manish Please have a look at update and suggest. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the inverse side of the association (the one with the `mappedBy` attribute). JPA only considers the owner side (the one *without* the `mappedBy` attribute).

You need to add the employee to all its service categories, and not just to add the service categories to the employee.

Comment: I understand that this is the inverse side of the association. But isn't there any way in which I can make this possible as I would like to make the ServiceCategory the owner.

Comment: The way is to do how I told you in my answer: `for (ServiceCategory sc : employee.getServiceCategories()) { sc.addEmployee(employee); }`